# How to set up a symbol server for Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to get religion with the new year and one of the things on my checklist is having a symbol server.

I'm using Visual Studio Team Services for both my source control and build controller.

I see where I'm supposed to enter the "Path To Publish Symbols"

[image]

But I don't know what goes in that field. Does Visual Studio Team Services automatically create a default Symbol Server I'm supposed to use and if so what is that path. If not what's the process for deploying a Symbol Server within Visual Studio Team Services?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Studio Team Services doesn't currently have Symbol Server support built-in to host the symbol server itself.  You may be interested in [this User Voice item](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2564053-treat-tfs-as-an-enterprise-symbol-server) so feel free to add votes to it.

Essentially, if you have your own build servers connected to Visual Studio Team Services, you'll want to give the UNC file path for your symbol server file share whether that exists on-premises or in the cloud (like in an Azure IaaS VM).

For anyone interested in learning more about this capability in TFS, I have a blog post here:  [Symbol Server Support in TFS](https://edsquared.com/source-server-and-symbol-server-support-in-tfs-2010-cf35ed5527e2)

Comment: Is there any guide on how to use azure as a symbol server?, What ports should I open, how do I secure the file share so only TS can write to it and only my team can read from it

Comment: @JuanZamudio - I'm not aware of any.  We're hoping to solve this in Visual Studio Team Services & Team Foundation Server.  There was an update to the User Voice item (http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2564053-treat-tfs-as-an-enterprise-symbol-server) and we're much closer now.  We need to make some changes to the debugger now to be able to authenticate correctly with VSTS and then we should have a good solution to ship.

Comment: i need this now!

Comment: The User Voice item has been updated, apparently a preview release will be available summer this year.

Comment: The preview release is available now

Comment: @mjroodt do you have a link to where to get the Preview Release?

Comment: @Crono which link is dead?  I clicked both and they worked.  The second one is redirecting to it's new home so I went ahead and updated that one.